# How to disable automatic insertion of matching braces in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

`pycharm` likes to do some extra typing for me: I put in `[` it puts in `]` : similarly for `(`, `{` (depending on context) and even `=` .  It is *not* helpful to me: usually there is something different intended.

I looked high and low through `Preferences|Editor` to see how to disable this but could not find that option. Pointers?

**Update**  I do have `Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys->Insert Paired Brackets and Quote` unchecked already

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll find what you're looking for in `Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys`. There's a whole bunch of settings there from smart indent to insertions, and what you're probably looking for is the `Insert paired brackets (), [], {}, <>` or something similar.

[Here is the link to their documentation on the matter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/completing-punctuation.html)

Comment: thanks - I do have those unchecked already : please see my update in the question

Comment: Hmm, strange. I tested it in my editor and it works as intended. I can check later, but perhaps look settings under `Editor -> Code Style -> Python` if something there might be interfering with the settings under `Smar keys`.

Comment: I did look at the _code style_ settings: but those appear to only be for _formatting_ and not for _editing_ .

Comment: Hmm, this is strange really, when I test with in pycharm, it works as intended. I'm sadly all out of ideas.

Comment: Not fixed yet - but upvoting as helpful